# Background Debug Module (BDM) recommendation for HCS08 controllers wanted

Tags: programmer

I have a number of Freescale MC9S08GT32 devices I plan to use in some projects if I can find the right toolchain. Code development would be Codewarrior, which is free for up to 32K of C code.
Programmer/debugger is Background Debug Module (BDM), but this doesn't seem to be standardized; at least I couldn't find one on the Freescale website. I found the following, with varying prices:

> [CNCgeeker](http://www.cncgeeker.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=7_4&products_id=10)
>       [PEmicro](http://www.pemicro.com/products/product_viewDetails.cfm?product_id=27)
>       [Softec microsystems](http://www.softecmicro.com/products.html?type=detail&title=inDART-One)
>       [Witztronics](http://www.witztronics.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2_25&products_id=53)

I guess there are others. I would like to know if you have experience with certain BDMs and which type you can recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using the P&E Micro [USB BDM Multilink Cable](http://www.pemicro.com/products/product_viewDetails.cfm?product_id=33) on a couple of HCS08 projects along with the Freescale/CodeWarrior HCS08 C compiler and it seems to work well (the CodeWarrior debugger "knows" about the P&E device).  A little more expensive ($99) than the lower cost bare-board units, but I like the fact that it is enclosed in a little case.

[image]

Comment: Yes, an enclosure is worth an extra cost for me too.

Answer (score 3):

The P&E Micro Multilink works great, but if you are looking for a cheaper solution there is the open source BDM project. Freescale maintains a forum at:
http://forums.freescale.com/t5/OSBDM-JM60-Open-Source-BDM-for/bd-p/OSBDM08

Bare circuit boards are available from:
Batchpcb dot com

The '9S08GT32 is a nice part, I have used it too.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the [Universal Background Debug Module JS16 from Witztronics](http://www.witztronics.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2_25&products_id=53) and it works great!

It is plug and play with the latest Codewarrior software packages.  Provides code download, step, break, run and many other debug features.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it works great"?  See the post notice: *We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more information.*

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the DEMO9s08SH8/SG8 BDM part of the board to work CodeWarrior from a XP VM on Win7. The open source version USBBDM has driver problems.

On the DEMO board pull the 08 processor and connect a BDM port cable between both. Use the PEmicro v10 drivers installed on the Win7 side and the drivers from the demo board on the XP side. I have shoved code and done tracing in this setup using CodeWarrior 6.3 Special Edition. Cost you might ask? $70.00 Problem solved. Need to migrate to the RS08 side. Development kit $70 = Same solution.